# iTextPDF not showing Japanese characters from XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to generate a PDF file using iTextPDF's XMLWorkerHelper. Originally, I am using Apache Velocity Template to generate an HTML code (hence the XMLWorkerHelper being used), but for this question I'll just provide a simple HTML line with Japanese Characters in it.

```
public class iTextJapChars {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("iTextJapChars.pdf");
    (new iTextJapChars()).generate(fos);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("done!");
}

public void generate(OutputStream os) throws IOException
{
    // create a document
    Document document = new Document();

    try
    {
        String content = "<html><head></head><body><div><p>begin　てすと end</p></div></body></html>";
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(content);
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

        // create a writer with an output stream passed as an argument
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
        document.addTitle("﻿身 元 保 証 書");
        document.addAuthor("れお");
        document.addSubject("");
        document.addKeywords("iText, PDF");
        document.addCreator("test.iTextPDF.generate() using iText");

        document.open(); // open the document now

        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, stream);

    }
    catch (DocumentException de) { throw new IOException(de.getMessage()); }
    finally { document.close(); } // close the document
}
```

The problem is, I can't get the resulting PDF file to show the Japanese characters. It only shows blank. Below are the things to note:

- CentOS 6.4
- iTextPDF 5.4.3
- XMLWorker 5.4.1
- Adobe Reader 9.5.5

Hope you can help me out here as I have been searching the net for more than a week now and I can't get any of the solutions to work using XMLWorkerHelper. If there is any information I have missed to mention, or I have mentioned a wrong info, please do tell me so I can update. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You didn't define a `FontProvider`, therefore XML Worker can only use the standard Type 1 font `Helvetica` and that font doesn't know how to draw Chinese, Japanese, Korean,... characters. Define a `FontProvider` and make sure you provide the appropriate font programs.

Comment: Hi Sir Bruno, thank you very much for your immediate response. It's an honor. I am now trying to define a FontProvider to get it working. I'm running through CSSResolver and the likes. I will update you once I get it working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Sir Bruno, unfortunately I can't still get it to work. I am fairly new in this and I am confused as to what function I have to use. The samples I've read lead me to declaring `CSSResolver`,`CssAppliers`,`HtmlPipelineContext`,`PdfWriterPipeline`,`HtmlPipeline`,`CssResolverPipeline`,`XMLWorker`, and `XMLParser`. The codes didn't get me anywhere near to showing the Japanese characters on the generated PDF. Would you be so kind to show me a documentation on to which how I can define the `FontProvider` to get it working? Or any documents that may be of help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't have such examples, because (1) I'm not the person who wrote XML Worker; the developers who did are only available on the paid ticketing system, and (2) I don't have the time to write new documentation on XML Worker because I have too much other things to do first. I'm sorry, you'll have to experiment yourself or ask somebody else...

Comment: Noted on that, Sir Bruno. Thanks for taking your time to respond. My sincerest gratitude.

Comment: I wonder if anyone else out there can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, stream,Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply SAN3, but it still does not return the Japanese characters. Will try the solution Sir Bruno mentioned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try with below logic it should work

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

pls check Adobe Reader 9.5.5 is able to red Japanese character, if not install language support from "http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/detail.jsp?ftpID=5877".

Adobe Reader will take the display languages present in your OS / machine. Given below link will show the language set up for windows 7
https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Language-in-Windows-7

Comment: As has already been mentioned in the comments to the question, a non-trivial cause of the OP's issue is his failure to use non-default fonts. The default font Helvetica simply does not contain glyphs for Japanese characters. Having fixed that, though, your proposal to properly provide the encoding of the stream might help making the code work.