# How to use Japanese language when convert html to pdf?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have html file with Japan language, I converted pdf file. But it don't show text Japanese.
This is my code :

```
final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("html.pdf"));
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream(filename), charset);
    document.close();
```

example : 
I have a line text : "ユーザロールを持つユーザだけが利用できるコンテンツ"
I want to add in pdf file by java then show in pdf file.

Comment: 1. which library you use for PdfWriter ?
2. what version you use ?

Comment: I am using itextpdf, version : 5.5.3

Comment: posibble duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821431/itextpdf-not-showing-japanese-characters-from-xmlworkerhelper

Comment: I saw it, but it don't help anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  [registry JAPANESE Font](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5/using-fonts)

```
public static final String DEST = "results/fonts/chinese.pdf";
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf";

public static final String CHINESE = "\u5341\u950a\u57cb\u4f0f";

public static final String JAPANESE = "\u8ab0\u3082\u77e5\u3089\u306a\u3044";

public static final String KOREAN = "\ube48\uc9d1";



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    File file = new File(DEST);

    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    new NotoExample().createPdf(DEST);

}



public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));

    document.open();

    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(TEXT, font);

    document.add(p);

    document.add(new Paragraph(CHINESE, font));

    document.add(new Paragraph(JAPANESE, font));

    document.add(new Paragraph(KOREAN, font));

    document.close();

}
```

}